# Play framework + java unable to save files to disk in prod mode

Tags: java, playframework

I am trying to store some jpg images to the disk from my play 
framework+java application. I am using activator run (in dev mode) and activator dist (in prod mode) for running the application. When I am running in dev mode directories and files are saved in the application class path. In prod mode files are not saved, but directories are created and shown as not writable/readable. What needs to be done for this to be solved?

Sample code:

```
File dir = new File(dirs);

dir.mkdirs();
dir.setWritable(true);
dir.setReadable(true);
dir.setExecutable(true);

String name = "fl" + "_" + sample;
File dest_f = new File(dir, name);//this is not creating the file in prod mode.
```

Thanks

Comment: By application classpath, you mean the temporary directory where Play compiles classes? On production mode classes are precompiled at startup and not mean to be updated, maybe that is the reason.
Anyway, that's not a good idea, why not specify a directory in the dict dedicated for your images?

Comment: Have you tried using `createNewFile()`? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile--

Comment: @Gonzalo Herreros ,I tried with directory outside the application classpath for saving the images and it works well for me. Thanks for the replies